# Edit form field value on template

Tags: django, forms, django-templates

I'm trying to edit the value of a form field inside a django template. I've tried a lot of stuff. I think the following is supposed to work:

```
{% with form.name.value="asdsad" %}

    {{form.name}}

{% endwith %}
```

But it presents the following error: `u'with' expected at least one variable assignment`

Nothing seems to work. What is the correct form of doing this?

Comment: django template cannot modify the object values like that. You should be doing this in the view ideally.

Comment: @karthikr Is there any way of doing it editing specifically the form field value?

Comment: why dont you use jquery to substitute the value of a field on document load?

Comment: do you want the default value to be shown as `asdsad`, and the user edits it  if needed? If so, look at adding a default value in the form's field.

Comment: @karthikr I wanted to change to a value that resides in a dictionary. I used `asdasd` for the demonstration. But even if I use the `default` filter it only shows the `value` field and not the hole form field. @Exprator I was interested only in Django Templating options.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to use jQuery. The form field can be referenced by `id = id_fieldname`. You can then change the attribute value by using `$('#id_fieldname).attr("value", new_value)`.

Suppose I want to edit `name` field of a form,

```
<script>
    var name_object = $('#id_name');
    var current_name = name_object.val();
    var new_name = "new_name"
    name_object.attr('value',new_name);
</script>
```

The id of the input tag of the HTML is always `id_fieldname`. Here, `fieldname` is the name given in the model.